# Help fixing dynamic graphics with multiple features

Tags: graphics, dynamic, cells, eventhandler

I'm trying to create a graph drawing widget, here are its basics that just allow you to create and drag vertices:

```
DynamicModule[{points = {{.5, .5}}, drag = False, idx},
 ExpressionCell[
  Style[EventHandler[
    Style[Graphics[Dynamic[Point[points]], PlotLabel -> Dynamic[drag],
       PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, ContentSelectable -> False], 
     Selectable :> CurrentValue["ShiftKey"], 
     ShowSelection -> True], {"MouseDown" :> 
      With[{pos = MousePosition["Graphics"]}, 
       idx = First[Nearest[points -> "Index", pos, {1, .01}], 
         Missing[]]; 
       If[points === {} || MissingQ[idx], AppendTo[points, pos], 
        drag = True];], {"MouseUp", 1} :> {(*Echo["Up!"];*)
       drag = False;}, 
     "MouseMoved" :> (If[drag && ! MissingQ[idx], 
         points[[idx]] = MousePosition["Graphics"]];), 
     "KeyDown" :> Echo[CurrentValue["EventKey"]]}, 
    PassEventsUp -> False, PassEventsDown -> True], 
   ContextMenu -> 
    Dynamic@With[{command = 
        ToString[Unevaluated[points = {}], InputForm]}, {MenuItem[
        "Clear", KernelExecute[ToExpression[command]], 
        MenuEvaluator -> Automatic]}]], ShowSelection -> False
  ]
 ]
```

I've managed to make it almost functional, one problem is that the "MouseUp" doesn't work properly when a point is stopped dragging, `Echo` fires, but `drag = False` does not for some reason, as can be seen in the PlotLabel that shows the `drag` variable.
I'm including a bunch of other elements to ensure that everything else also works because I'm struggling to fix one thing without breaking another ‍.

- Dragging should stop when MouseUp fires
- Key events should all trigger
- Context menu should work
- Graphics should be resizable (at least after double-clicking with ShiftKey)

Maybe there is a different way of achieving everything above?

Another thing is the problematic way of regaining focus after resizing the Graphics, key events either stop working or FrontEnd starts beeping at me with "You tried to edit inside a subexpression that cannot be edited because it is a fixed special form". I need to select some other cell and then the widget cell again, only then does it starts processing keys normally.